# Usage of IF condition in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to create model in which i want to collect the specific colored(**RED**) agents at a specific location (**A**). I am using a transfer table to divert the flow from one conveyor to other. 
Can any body help me how to divert the flow based on the colors of agent.
attached snaps of discrete event diagram. Please let me know if you require more information.
[discrete eve dia 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUTO6.png)
[image showing collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oRv6.png)

Answer (score 0):

A transfer table cannot actively steer where agents go. Instead, you have to manage where agents should be transfered in the "Convey" block as below. Put in a condition based on the agent color and send them to the respective end nodes or conveyors.

Hope this helps

[image]